# What is the "bash" process name meaning

Tags: linux, bash, process, long-running-processes

I have checked the process in my Linux system I found there is lots of process running with the name **bash**
And if we Kill them all

attaching a [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKm6a.png)screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the only user connected to that machine? It could be that you opened multiple bash sessions e.g. by typing the command `bash` you launch a new login session and a new process appears in the process list.

Comment: No there is multiple users who connected with the machine.

Comment: You can use the command `w` to see which users are logged into the machine. If there's only a few users connected a bunch of bash processes in the process list, it's very likely that users just opened multiple bash sessions.